# MIMIC-III PROCEDUREEVENTS_MV overlapping invasive ventilation time

Tags: mimic-iii

I am working on invasive ventilation records in PROCEDUREEVENTS_MV.

I found a few records where there are overlapping times. I already checked that those records has `cancelreason = 0` and `statusdescription in ('FinishedRunning', 'Stopped', 'Paused')`.

Do you have any suggestions / guidelines on how I should clean them up?

From my understanding, I have two options: take the last record stored or merge them.

For instance (PostgreSQL),

```
select hadm_id, icustay_id, itemid, label, starttime, endtime,
value, valueuom, storetime, cancelreason, statusdescription
from procedureevents_mv join d_items using (itemid)
where hadm_id = 103885 and itemid = 225792 and cancelreason = 0
order by storetime;
```

returns

```
hadm_id icustay_id  itemid  label                   starttime           endtime             value   valueuom    storetime           cancelreason    statusdescription
103885  286523      225792  Invasive Ventilation    2174-02-24 14:05:00 2174-02-24 18:09:00 244.0   min         2174-02-24 14:08:00 0               FinishedRunning
103885  286523      225792  Invasive Ventilation    2174-02-24 10:03:00 2174-02-24 18:07:00 484.0   min         2174-02-25 17:51:00 0               FinishedRunning
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a generic answer - I'd read the patient nursing notes to get more information about what may have happened (e.g. a spontaneous breathing trial). Merging the times seems reasonable. An alternative option is to use the ventilation duration query I wrote which uses ventilator settings instead of the PROCEDUREEVENTS_MV table: https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/master/etc/ventilation-durations.sql